# Net.rim.crypto not found

Tags: blackberry, cryptography, rsa

I've been trying to use cryptography in my BlackBerry application (using net.rim.crypto library) but when I try to run it on a 5.0 BlackBerry device, the app doesn't open and I get the message "net.rim.crypto not found".

What I need to do to use RSA encryption (of text) in my app running on a 5.0 device?

Answer (score 1):

The `net.rim.crypto` package does not exist in the BlackBerry OS, at least as far as I am aware. If you want to do encryption/cryptography on BlackBerries, you should use the [net.rim.device.api.crypto](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/package-summary.html) package instead.

Comment: That's the package I'm using... The name is different on the device.